# Multi-dimensional Array - Check for diagonal consecutive values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Writing a check for an array to determine if there are any potential consecutive `values` within it, be it `horizontal`, `vertical`, or either way `diagonal`. The example below is a sample diagonal, but I need it working both ways `/` and `\`.

### **Fiddle Away:** http://jsfiddle.net/PXPn9/10/

**So let's make a pretend scenario...**

```
var b = [ 
    [ 0, 0, X, 0, 0 ]
    [ 0, 0, 0, X, 0 ]
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, X ]
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]
```

**Using a basic 2 level deep loop, which iterates over the whole thing and uses some ternary operators to identify "wins"**

```
function testWin() {
    var win=3, len=b.length, r=0, c=0, dr=0, dl=0;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<len;j++){

        // COL WIN CHECK //
            (b[j][i]==="X") ? c++ : c=0;

        // ROW WIN CHECK //
            (b[i][j]==="X") ? r++ : r=0;

        // DIAG WIN CHECK //
            // (b[i][j]==="X" && b[i+1][j+1]==="X") ? dr++ : dr=0;
            // (b[j][i]==="X" && b[i+1][j+1]==="X") ? dl++ : dl=0;
        // WIN CHECK FOR ALL 4
            if(c===win || r===win){ alert("YOU WIN!"); return true;}
        }
        r=0;
    }
}
```

The `horizontal check` and the `vertical check` appear to work flawlessly, until I enable the commented attempts to create a diagonal test... Could I have somebody take a look at the diagonal tests and help identify why enabling them breaks everything, and what I have done wrong?

**I would like assistance with this in particular to create a `diagonal` check. (view JSFiddle for whole source)**

```
    // DIAG WIN CHECK //
        // (b[i][j]==="X" && b[i+1][j+1]==="X") ? dr++ : dr=0;
        // (b[j][i]==="X" && b[i+1][j+1]==="X") ? dl++ : dl=0;
```

### **Fiddle Away:** http://jsfiddle.net/PXPn9/10/

---

**NEW COMMENT**
I've tried this, for example, but it is hard coded for a diagonal of 3 (I need it to expand later to use the `win` variable). When I add this though, the bottom right corner of my `horizontal` and `vertical` checks fails.

```
    // if((b[i][j] && b[i+1][j+1] && b[i+2][j+2])==="X"){ alert("YOU WON! Diag1"); return true; }
    // if((b[i][j] && b[i+1][j-1] && b[i+2][j-2])==="X"){ alert("YOU WON! Diag2"); return true; }
```

I know it has something to do with the values of dl and dr aren't resetting properly, and its affecting the other horizontal and vertical tests, but I'm a tad lost of an effective way to solve it.

Comment: I know it has something to do with the values of `dl` and `dr` aren't resetting properly, and its affecting the other `horizontal` and `vertical` tests, but I'm a tad lost of an effective way to do it.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, You already asked for this days ago, and I gave you a working answer

Comment: Yes you did Edgar, and I am expanding on it and trying to build my knowledge by utilizing ternary operators. The problem with your answer was that it forced the horizontal and vertical and diagonal check across the entire board, and now I am expanding to make it a limited version, and also to check for internal diagonals that are not the length of the board.

Comment: I will certainly do that, as your post is what made me expand into this solution in the first place :-)

Comment: Thanks. Let me see what I can do here :)

Comment: using the ternary if operator like this is not recommended, because it becomes hard to read and doesn't return a value, for what the ternary was designed. just use if else

Comment: Thank you @metadings. I have it working just fine with if/else. I am trying to write a golfed project :-P Not for a contest, but for my own challenge. Just hit a small road block on the diagonal. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Create a simple helper function to map 2D point coordinates to your array. For example: `function pointToIndex(x, y) { return y * width + x; }`. Then tweak a flood-fill algorithm to detect your scenarios. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Well, considering this runs every single time a move is made, and often times there can be up to 100 moves, is recursion the way to truly minimize this code? Love the solution, btw.

Comment: @Nicholas why do you need to check for diagonals that don't have the length of the board? They will never be a win

Comment: Because I'm going to add a method to change the `win` variable to the square root of the board x 2 floored... so a grid of 10x10 would potentially consist of requiring 6 in a row. Making "connect 4" on a whole new scale, with no requirement to "drop" your pieces, making the game more difficult.

Comment: Answers do not go inside the question. If you have an answer, you need to post it below *as an answer*. It's also never appropriate to edit pseudo tags like `[solved]` into the title of your question.

Comment: I apologize. I'm used to a different forum. I like people to think about their answers instead of just get a pre-scripted answer. I will fix these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
(b[i][j]==="X" && i===j) ? dl++ : 0;
(b[j][i]==="X" && (i+j)===(len-1)) ? dr++ : 0;
```

?

`dl` or the left diagonal would have `i` and `j` equal(so (0,0) (1,1) and (2,2))

`dr` or the right diagonal would have the sum of `i` and `j` equal to side-length minus 1(so (0,2) (1,1) (2,0))

This would work when the length of the diagonal is the same as the length of the matrix, full-body diagonal in a tic-tac-toe game, for example. For partial diagonals you can modify the code slightly to something like:

```
var diff = 0;
var sum = len - 1;  
(b[i][j]==="X") ? diff = (i-j) : diff = 0;  
(b[i][j]==="X") ? sum= (i+j) : sum = len;  
(b[i][j]==="X" && (i-j)===diff) ? dl++ : 0;
(b[j][i]==="X" && (i+j)===sum) ? dr++ : 0;
```

Comment: The problem with that is it could be, for example, `[0,3],[1,4],[2,5]`

Comment: @NicholasHazel Yeah, I have added a possible fix for that. See my last edit

Comment: Oh, I see where you're going... Hmm, direct port didn't work, but I see the logical pathway. Let me play tomorrow. Thanks for the answer, I think you have my solution bottled up and I just need to snap the cork. Will mark as accepted tomorrow if I get it going!

Comment: I see, I believe this will totally work for me, but I have to identify what is breaking the horizontal/vertical/diagonal check in one go. It appears to be giving me false positives.

Comment: @NicholasHazel I may have 'cork'ed the problem. Same logic, slightly different implementation. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Y7VUQ/5/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44858/discussion-between-tewathia-and-nicholas-hazel)

Answer (score 0):

#### Final answer (due to @tewathia's answer and some further research)

```
function testWin() {
    var win=3, len=b.length, r=0, c=0, dr=0, dl=0;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<len;j++){
            (b[j][i]==="X") ? c++ : c=0;
            (b[i][j]==="X") ? r++ : r=0;
            if(b[i][j]==="X" && i<len-win+1){ dr=0; dl=0;
                for(var z=0;z<win;z++){ 
                    (b[i+z][j+z]==="X") ? dr++ : dr=0;
                    (b[i+z][j-z]==="X") ? dl++ : dl=0;
                }
            }
            if(c===win || r===win || dr===win || dl===win){ alert("YOU WIN!"); return true;}
        } r=0;
    }
}
```

### Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/atk3V/1/